# Programmatically start an asp.net integrated webserver with visual studio files

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight-3.0, webdev.webserver

I'm not sure what keywords to google for, so i'm gonna ask SO.

I have an asp.net website which host a database, wcf dll and silverlight application. I would like to create an .exe file to automatically run an integrated webserver with the application root being the project folder of where my asp.net files are.

Basically what I want to do is run the project in localhost with 1 click without starting up visual studio. Starting up the webserver, browser and redirecting to that localhost url.

The computer I will distribute this to may not have visual studio installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with Cassina found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/dmitryr/attachment/8975821.ashx).  WebDev.WebServer.exe was built on that.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following article in which I have used C# to start the webdev server.

http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/367_Unit_Testing_ASP_NET_Pages_Using_WatiN.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just want to let you know : There is a new feature in Asp.NET 4.0 ; `Auto-Start` :

> The new "auto start" feature of ASP.NET 4 and IIS 7.5 provides a well-defined approach that allows you to perform expensive application startup and pre-cache logic that can run before any end-users hit your application.  This enables you to have your application "warmed up" and ready from the very beginning, and deliver a consistent high performance experience.

`More:` [Auto-Start ASP.NET Applications (VS 2010 and .NET 4.0 Series)](http://tinyurl.com/owkch6)